# Object is not a primitive for response message models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I decorated an action as follows

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of customers", typeof(List<CustomerDto>))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(NotFoundException))]
```

The OK model is shown correctly.

However, under Repsonse Messages, I get 'Object is not a primitive' for `NotFound`. The custom exception derives from `Exception`, implements `ISerializable` and also has `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract()]`

How can I show the actual data type instead of the message?

Also, do I incur a performance hit when using the WebApi normally, if I decorate all actions with such attributes?

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of customers", typeof(IEnumerable<int>))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(BadRequestErrorMessageResult))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(NotFoundResult))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
            return Ok(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else if (id == 0)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return BadRequest("id must be greater than 0");
    }
```

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#!/IHttpActionResult/IHttpActionResult_GetById